# Confidence Interval question for amount of experiments one should do.

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, binomial-distribution, confidence-interval

Before posing this question, the lecture notes I am reading discussed games, probability, the binomial distribution and central limit theorem. It usually assumes some form of game when it asks something. This question has been confusing me a bit:

> How many experiments do we need to perform to estimate with $90$% confidence a winning
>   probability within an accuracy of $1$%? And if we want an accuracy of $0.1$%?

We want to estimate $p$, let us use $\hat{p}$. Normally the confidence interval for $90$% certainty for a binomial distribution (win/lose) is given by:
$$(\hat{p}-\frac{ 1.645 \sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}}{\sqrt{N}},\hat{p}+\frac{ 1.645 \sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}}{\sqrt{N}} ) $$

Here we have that the last bit is the uncertainty, we want this to be equal to $1$% so $0.01$, we then get that:
$$ 0.01=\frac{1.645 \sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}}{\sqrt{N}} $$

We get that we should at least pick:
$$ N \geq   1.645^2\hat{p}(1-\hat{p}) \cdot 10^4$$

Is it true that I cannot directly compute $\hat{p}$ from how the answer is phrased and this would be the best answer?

The answer for the second question will be:
$$ N \geq   1.645^2\hat{p}(1-\hat{p}) \cdot 10^6$$

---

By symmetry of  the zeros of $f(x)=x(1-x)$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$, we know that this estimate for $N$ is maximised whenever $\hat{p}= \frac{1}{2}$. This would indeed correspond to the worst case scenario for an estimator.
$$ N_1 \geq 1.645^2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot 10^4 \approx 6765 $$
And similarly: 
$$ N_2 \geq 1.645^2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot 10^6 \approx 676506 $$

Comment: You may want to use the fact that $x(1-x)$ is maximised when $x=\frac12$

Comment: Consider a Bernoulli game and suppose $N$ games are played and the outcomes recorded as the variates $X_1=x_1,\dotsc, X_N=x_N$. Then an estimate of $p$ is given by 
$$\hat{p}=\frac{X_1+\dotsc +X_N}{N},$$
so that actually $\hat{p}$ is a function of the sample size $N$. If we want the standard error of a $90\%$ confidence interval to be equal to $0.01$, then, indeed, we must have $N$ at least $\geq 2.576^2 \hat{p}(1-\hat{p})10^4$—but the RHS still depends on $N$ here! So you must use Henry's suggestion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By symmetry of  the zeros of $f(x)=x(1-x)$, we know that this estimate for $N$ is maximised whenever $\hat{p}= \frac{1}{2}$
$$ N_1 \geq 1.645^2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot 10^4 \approx 6765 $$
And similarly: 
$$ N_2 \geq 1.645^2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot 10^6 \approx 676506 $$